# loading wrong jvm.dll

Tags: 64-bit, path, jvm, java

When I run an executable I created, it uses the jvm.dll from C:\Windows\System32.  But I want it to use the jvm.dll in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\jre\bin\server.

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\jre\bin\server ***is*** in my PATH environment variable.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem use same bit software mean if you are using 32bit Flex sdk then use 32 bit jdk and if you are using 64 bit Flex sdk then use 64 bit jdk

Answer (score 0):

Is your jdk1.6.0_17 path **before** the windows\system32 path in your PATH variable?

Another thing to try would be to set "JAVA_HOME" to the root directory of your non-system32 JRE install.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I have my jdk1.6.0_17 path as the very first path.
I already have JAVA_HOME set to C:\Program Files\Java\Jdk1.6.0_17.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

c:\windows\system32\java.exe is just a hook

and it loads default jvm from program files

do you know which one is it loading in your case?